# Does the following inequality hold? (Integral inequality)

Tags: inequality

Consider that $g\triangleq\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y,z)dxdydz$, where $f(x,y,z)>0$ for $0<x,y,z<1$.

Let $\widehat g=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,x,x)dxdydz=\int_0^1f(x,x,x)dx$.

Then  I get $\widehat g<g$.

Is the result $\widehat g<g$ correct?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider what happens for the this piecewise function: $f(x,y,z) =\epsilon$ if $x=y=z$  and $1$ otherwise.